# Is it advisable to use the spread operator to store user input in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, security, mongoose

I'm using Joi library to validate input from users and mongoose schema to validate data sent to Mongodb?
I find myself using the `spread operator` after *validating* the input to quickly store the data in a mongoose data model, like this:

```
 validate(req.body.inputObject);
    //...
    
    const newData = {...req.body.inputObject } /// spread operator here!!!
    //...
    if /* required additional data */ {
        newData.more = {
            _id: someId,
            value: someValue,
        }
    }
    //...
    const data = Data.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newData, { new: true });
    
    // check and report error, otherwise
    res.send(data);
```

I know that mongoose stores only the properties found in the Schema of an object in the database. Therefore, any additional data passed by the user that is not in the schema is dropped. The alternative, as I see it, is something like this:

```
    validate(req.body.inputObject);
    //...
    const newData = {
        value1: req.body.inputObject.value1,
        value2: req.body.inputObject.value2,
        ...
        valueN: req.body.inputObject.valueN,
    }
    //...
    if /* require additional data */ {
        newData.more = {
            _id: someId,
            value: someValue,
        }
    }
    //...
    const data = Data.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newData, { new: true });
    // check and report error, otherwise
    res.send(data);
```

The `spread operator` approach is flexible because I do not need to know/guess what values in the `data object` the user wants to update. Better, I dont have to assume that the user will provided values for all the properties of the object including the modifications they want to make. This way, users can send just the updated properties. This is not the case for the second approach.

**My question is:** are there any down sides or security concerns for using the `spread operator` in situations like this?
Is it bad to rely on mongoose dropping properties not found in the schema?

Is there a better approach that is both flexible and secure?

Or, should I stick with the second approach and expect users to send all the properties along with updates?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain I would rely on mongoose to drop properties (especially if mongodb support dollar operators etc. in update queries, I wouldn't want the user input be able to provide those), but another worry would be inadvertently using that `newData` object in other parts of your application logic, not just mongo stores.

Comment: "*should I expect users to send all the properties along with updates?*" - that's an API design question and not really related to the implementation issue. Notice it requires the user to always load the entire object before sending an update, and causes more problems for concurrent updates.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the response. I forgot about `dollar operators`. Yes it would be really bad if users could send in those as input.